If I connect to my work VPN from inside a virtual machine, will my real machine's network traffic still be routed through the VPN?
When working from home, I must connect to my company's VPN, using Cisco Anyconnect, before I can remote into my work machine.
What happens if I connect from inside a virtual machine? Will my real machine's traffic still be routed through the VPN, or will it be treated as just another device on the network, like my smartphone, safe from any potential tracking?
For context, my machine runs Fedora, though I installed Ubuntu on the VM. Unfortunately, I can't speak to the VPN's configuration.
After reading through answers to similar questions, I gathered that I can configure the VM to use a bridged network adapter to make it look like a separate machine, but I'm not sure if that's enough to protect my real machine.

VPN connections created inside the VM will only affect the VMs traffic. The host system won't even know its there. the traffic that makes up the VPN tunnel will pass through the hosts hardware, but the host cannot inject into nor read traffic inside the tunnel. the particular configuration of the VPN does not matter, nor does the network type you have configured in your virtualization software (other than host-only of course, because then you couldnt connect to the VPN in the first place).

@FrankThomas Thank you! By "host", are you talking about my real machine or the company's servers?

By host he means your real machine.

Sorry, in virtualization terminology, VMs are "guests", and the physical/real computer the VMs run on is the "host". If you connect from a VM using AnyConnect only that VMs traffic will be sent to the companies network through the VPN. the real PCs traffic will just go out through the LAN and your Internet connection like there was no VPN at all. your idea will probably work as long as your VM performs well enough for you to establish a smooth and reliable remote connection to the work system.
